# Script tag before DOCTYPE

Tags: doctype

Can I write this:

```
<script>var _XXX = false;</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or it will cause a problem to the page?

I mean that the script will be before the doctype

Answer (score 2):

Writing the DOCTYPE first is certainly best practice.

> The  declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML
>   document, before the  tag.
>
> The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to
>   the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

I'd say, just something experienced web developers do to avoid horrible, elusive bugs.

Comment: OK BUT, as we use the current browsers (IE7+, FF, CH, OP, Safari and so on) will it cause an error on the page? will it "Break" the page?

Comment: Some browsers may act differently, i cannot say that they will. Why not add it later?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write it before DOCTYPE only thing is that it will show a waring that the location of script tag is invalid but anyhow it will work, but following the best practices its good to write after that if u have a head tag its better to place the script under it.

Answer (score 0):

Doctype declaration must be the first part of the page. Doctype defines the version of the HTML. But  tag before the doctype will work. It is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It'll defeat the point of using a DOCTYPE, since the browser will behave exactly the same as if you had not provided a DOCTYPE, as will validators except that the validator will report an extra error of "stray doctype".